# Could not map index document field to property "Paths" on type Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem

Tags: solr, content-search, indexing

Has anyone seen this error in the logs

```
Could not map index document field to property "Paths" on type Sitecore.ContentSearch.SearchTypes.SearchResultItem. Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx). Actual value: [orphan]
```

It looks like the item is published in the `web` database but `SOLR` is not `indexing` it properly.

We have done `re-publish` and `re-index` several times but nothing is making any difference. We can navigate to the page like `/news/news1` but it is not coming up on the `/news-listing` page and the news-listing page is blank.

Comment: Did you ever find out how the [orphan] value ended up in the index?

Answer (score 1):

After troubleshooting for many hours, we looked into the raw solr query for an effected item via the SOLR admin interface:

```
query: _uniqueid:97338416-a07a-4f0b-8078-7437b192e0e7
```

that retured this raw field in the SOLR:

```
"_path":["262cd6ec48c941f7834707930b0f0389",
"72a997bbf0224cd7bc326ffcbfc00f9a",
"97338416a07a4f0b80787437b192e0e7",
"[orphan]",
"b7d2a71b2a544a869ab1f504cdf721aa",
"dc604fdff08d408cbbc54a472a338d2a",
"e5565a00531047179478262d23104319",
"fbab412c5dbf4882acd732b2cabe1fce",
"fe621d54c6c049639fe4ec330b5bc032"]}]
```

The value of [orphan] was the issue and no matter how many times we published or re-indexed it didn't go away.

Then we ran these jobs from /sitecore/admin/dbcleanup.aspx

Cleanup Orphans
Cleanup Orphan Fields
Rebuild Descendants

[image]

Re-ran the SOLR index and all the results were back.